# C++ dynamic array cleared when object returned

Tags: c++, templates, dynamic-arrays, multiset

I'm currently working on an assignment (so I'd rather no post the full code) trying to implement a Bag abstract data type.

Below is a method which I am currently trying to implement:

```
template <typename T>
Bag<T> Bag<T>::operator+ (const Bag<T>& bag) {
    int sizeofCurrentMultiset = cardinality_;
    int sizeofPassedMultiset  = bag.cardinality_;
    int totalSize = sizeofCurrentMultiset + sizeofPassedMultiset;

    Bag<T> newBag(totalSize);

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeofCurrentMultiset; i++) {
        newBag.insert(array_[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeofPassedMultiset; i++) {
        newBag.insert(bag.array_[i]);
    }

    return newBag;
}
```

I'm storing the elements as a dynamic array.

My problem is that when the new bag is returned, I can print the cardinality fine (prints to 4, the original bags had two elements each), but the dynamic array doesn't contain the numbers (it prints out some random numbers such as -1789102). However when I try print out the elements before the bag is returned, it prints out fine.

No doubt it will be something trivial, but I'd appreciate the help.

Thanks.

Comment: This code looks fine. It's likely that the problem lies in your `insert` method, or perhaps in your copy constructor if `insert` uses copy semantics.

Comment: Can you post the code that is used to print everything?

Comment: Have you written a copy constructor for `Bag`? Sounds like you might be getting the default copy constructor.

Comment: Can you post copy constructor for `Bag<T>`. It will be invoked when `operator+()` returns and is the most likely cause as all is fine before function returns.

Comment: Additionally to the copy constructor mentioned by Steve you'll also need an assignment operator.

Comment: @everyone Thanks for the comments guys. Yes, after reading over my class material it looks like it probably is just missing the copy constructor. I'll implement this and get back to you!

Comment: @SteveO'Connor - post your answer. Get your credits.

Comment: I implemented the copy constructor and it is working fine :) Thanks for the help! care to post an answer? :)

Comment: @TomFitton: I posted an answer but deleted it, since, it is hard to implement a copy contructor without knowing the details of `Bag` class. But you can post your own solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write a copy constructor for your `Bag` class. Looks like you are getting the default constructor which only does a shallow copy of your class. This is why the `cardinality` member is ok but your dynamic array is not. The copy constructor is called when your `operator+` function returns the `Bag` object.